# Solve nonlinear Recurrence Relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve the following recurrence relation for general constants $c_1,c_2,c_3$:

$R(k) = c_1 + \frac{c_2}{R(k-1)}$, $R(0)=c_3$

I got a solution from Mathematica, but can't figure out how to get there.

Comment: Any ideas? Anything you've tried?

Comment: I tried using a generating function and stared at the coefficients, but the division made things messy and I didn't really know what to do.

Comment: That's a start. Try putting what you just told me in the post :)

Comment: Continued fraction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change variables to $u_k = R(k) - c_1$, you get a Ricatti recurrence:

$\begin{align*}
   u_{k + 1}
     &= \frac{c_2}{u_k + c_1}
\end{align*}$

Ricatti recurrences have the form:

$\begin{align*}
  w_{n + 1} 
    &= \frac{a w_n + b}{c w_n + d}
\end{align*}$

where $c \ne 0$ and $a d \ne b c$.

A way to solve them is to use the substitution $x_n = 1 / (1 + \eta w_n)$, which gives after light massage:

$\begin{align*}
  x_{n + 1}
    &= \frac{(d \eta - c) x_n + c}
            {(b \eta^2 - (a - d) \eta - c) x_n + a \eta + c}
\end{align*}$

Pick $\eta$ so this reduces to a linear recurrence, and you are set.